# Informação sobre segurança ao inserir dados

Tags: php, mysqli

O Mysqli (Mysql Extendido) tem maior segurança e eu até agora achava que não precisava tratar os dados de variaveis antes de adicionar no banco, mas estudando [nessa página](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) encontrei este código similar ao que eu usava no antigo MySQL. Realmente é necessário usar este código para tratar os dados antes de inserir no banco.

Código:

```
$variavel="'" . $conexao->real_escape_string('col1_value') . "'";
```

No caso, eu sempre uso o *Prepared Statements*, então, só ele resolve ou tenho que adicionar isso também?

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida

Comment: Não tá faltando uma interrogação ali em *"Realmente é necessário..."*?

Answer (score 1):

Os `preparedStatements` são interpretados pelo banco de daados e armazenados lá enquanto sua conexão estiver ativa. Ao serem lidos, o banco de dados já interpreta os tipos de dados que devem ir em cada `placeholder`, portanto caso você passe um parâmetro com o tipo incorreto (ou um `SQL` válido, por exemplo), o banco de dados simplesmente vai dar erro. Para o caso de campos textos, o banco de dados até vai aceitar o SQL, mas ele vai ser salvo na coluna deste campo ao invés de ser executado de fato.

Do ponto de vista de segurança não se deve confiar nem mesmo no que vem do banco de dados, por situações como esta do usuário salvar um SQL em um campo textual. Mas isto seria mais nas situações de `SELECT` do que nas situações `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`.

**Atualização**

Verifiquei o site mencionado e percebi que o sujeito está utilizando queries concatenadas. Ele vai concatenando SQL com as variáveis vindas do usuário e por isso ele utiliza o escape. Nos exemplos que ele utiliza `preparedStatements` ele também não dá escape.